# For loop vs Numpy vectorization computation time

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

I was randomly comparing the computation times of **an explicit for-loop** with **vectorized implementation in numpy**. I ran exactly 1 million iterations and found some astounding differences. For-loop took about **646ms** while the `np.exp()` function computed the same result in **less than 20ms**.

```
import time
import math
import numpy as np

iter = 1000000

x = np.zeros((iter,1))
v = np.random.randn(iter,1)

before = time.time()

for i in range(iter):
    x[i] = math.exp(v[i])
after = time.time()
print(x)
print("Non vectorized= " + str((after-before)*1000) + "ms")

before = time.time()
x = np.exp(v)
after = time.time()
print(x)
print("Vectorized= " + str((after-before)*1000) + "ms")
```

The result I got:

```
 [[0.9256753 ]
 [1.2529006 ]
 [3.47384978]
 ...
 [1.14945181]
 [0.80263805]
 [1.1938528 ]]
Non vectorized= 646.1577415466309ms
[[0.9256753 ]
 [1.2529006 ]
 [3.47384978]
 ...
 [1.14945181]
 [0.80263805]
 [1.1938528 ]]
Vectorized= 19.547224044799805ms
```

My questions are:

1. What exactly is happening in the second case? The first one is using
   an explicit for-loop and thus the computation time is justified.
   What is happening "behind the scenes" in the second case?
2. How can one implement such computations (second case) without using numpy (in plain Python)?

Comment: You will never implement something with that sort of runtime in pure Python. Even an empty for loop would have tremendous overhead compared to the optimized C code that is doing the looping in the second case.

Comment: `numpy` only does that because it uses C code underneath to do the vectorizations

Comment: Check [this *outstanding* video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw) from Jake Vanderplas (one of the core developers of scikit learn). Very simple language, very intuitive. Don't think can explain better

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There was a little computational error from my side. (100 to 1000 scale for ms computation)

Comment: Function calls and loops have a very high overhead in Python. If you wan't to avoid that use Numba, or Cython to implement algorithms using plain loops efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that NumPy is calling high quality numerical libraries ([BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) for instance) which are very good at vector arithmetic.

I imagine you could specifically call the exact libraries used by NumPy, however, NumPy would likely know best which to use.

Answer (score 2):

NumPy is a Python wrapper over libraries and code written in C. This is a large part of the efficiency of NumPy. C code compiles directly to instructions which are executed by your processor or GPU. On the other hand, Python code must be interpreted as it executes. Despite the ever increasing speed we can get from interpreted languages with advances like Just In Time Compilers, for some tasks they will never be able to approach the speed of compiled languages.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to the fact that Python does not have direct access to the hardware level.

Python can't use the [SIMD (Single instruction, multiple data)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) assembly instructions that most modern CPU's and GPU's have. These SIMD instruction allow a single operation to execute on a vector of data all at once (within a single clock cycle) at the hardware level.

NumPy on the other hand has functions built in C, and C is a language capable of running SIMD instructions. Therefore NumPy can take advantage of the vectorization hardware in your processor.